# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x) = \left(1-\frac{x^2}{n} \right)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

---

> For $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we define $f_n(x) = \left(1-\frac{x^2}{n} \right)^n$. Determine if $f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent on: 
>  1.
> $[-A,A]$ for $A>0$ 
>  2.
> $\mathbb{R}$

---

Sol for 1:

First of all, we know $f_n$ is pointwise convergent to $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$. By definition of uniform convergence we need to look at $\lim_{n \to \infty } \sup_{x\in [-A,A]}\left| f_n(x)-f(x)\right|$ and check whether it's $0$ or not.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty } \sup_{x\in [-A,A]}\left| f_n(x)-f(x)\right|=\lim_{n \to \infty } \sup_{x\in [-A,A]}\left|\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n} \right)^n-e^{-x^2}\right|$$

I'm not sure how to find the limit (I get confused because there are 2 variables $n,x$).
I'd appreciate if you could help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: @HallaSurvivor No, Note that there are discussing about different expression. Also, I ask about uniform convergence in $\mathbb{R}$ and not only $[-A,A]$.

Comment: **Hint :** For 1., write $\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n} \right)^n = \exp\left( n \ln \left(1-\frac{x^2}{n} \right) \right)$ and use the inequality $\ln(1+u) \geq u-u^2/2$. For 2., an option is to prove that a uniform limit of polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ is necessarily a polynomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Notice that, for any $n$, $$\sup_{x\in[-A,A]}\left|\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\right)^n-e^{-x^2}\right|=\sup_{x\in[0,A^2]}\left|\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n-e^{-x}\right|.$$
   (I'm only making this step to make things less messy, it's not strictly necessary). Now, for all $A$, for all large enough $n$ and all $x\in[0,A^2]$, we have $1-\frac{x}{n}>0$, so we can take the logarithm of $1-\frac{x}{n}$, and, in particular, we have
   $$\left|\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n-e^{-x}\right|=\left|e^{n\log(1-x/n)}-e^{-x}\right|=\left|e^{-x}\left(e^{n\log(1-x/n)+x}-1\right)\right|\leq\left|e^{n\log(1-x/n)+x}-1\right|.$$
   $n\log(1-x/n)+x\leq 0$ for all $x\in[0,A^2]$, and is decreasing, since it is equal to $0$ at $x=0$ and its derivative is $1-\frac{n}{n-x}$ which is at most $0$ for all $x\geq 0$. Hence the supremum of $\left|e^{n\log(1-x/n)+x}-1\right|$ on $[0,A^2]$ occurs at $x=A^2$, where it equals
   $$1-e^{A^2}\left(1-\frac{A^2}{n}\right)^n\to 1-e^{A^2}e^{-A^2}=0$$
   as $n\to\infty$, so we have the desired uniform convergence.
2. Each $f_n$ is unbounded on $\mathbb{R}$, yet the pointwise limit is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$, so the convergence cannot possibly be uniform.

Comment: Can you explain why $n\log(1-x/n)+x$ is decreasing? Is it obtained from $1-\frac{n}{n-x}$? how do you show $1-\frac{n}{n-x}\le 0$ ?

Comment: Just to make sure, you get $\sup_{x\in[-A,A]}\left|\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\right)^n-e^{-x^2}\right|=\sup_{x\in[0,A^2]}\left|\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n-e^{-x}\right|\le1-e^{A^2}\left(1-\frac{A^2}{n}\right)^n\to 0 $ and in conclusion $f_n \xrightarrow[]{u}f$?

Comment: @Lior, you prove that $n\log(1-x/n)+x$ is decreasing using the derivative $1-n/(n-x)$ as you mentioned. You show that $1-n/(n-x)\leq 0$ by multiplying both sides by $n-x$, noting that this won't flip the inequality if $n$ is large enough, since $x$ is bounded above by $A^2$. Your summary of the argument in the second comment is correct.